# Concatenate cells in column based on criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to concatenate cells in a column. the model begins with a model number without any `.` the options to that model begin with `.` I would like the marco to concatenate all the way until the beginning of the next model number (the next cell that does not begin with `.`) , then repeat process, I have provided a an example below. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**current State**

```
abc

.bcr

.kjl

.plk

ghy

.ytr

.ihgew

.rth

.u

.lpn

trh

.pjkjh

.dsgyudd

.hg

.gfd
```

**Future State**

```
abc.bcr.kjl.plk

ghy.ytr.ihgew.rth.u.lp

trh.pjkjh.dsgyudd.hg.gfd
```

Comment: Please post what you've tried first and then others will be more prone to helping you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ConditionalConcatenate()
'col A contain the texts and col B in corresponding row hold concatenated result

Dim strDone As String
Dim rngg As Range, lastcolA As Range, rngused As Range
Dim counted As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer

Range("B:B").ClearContents
strDone = ""
Set rngg = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")
Set lastcolA = rngg.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
Set rngused = Range("A1:A" & lastcolA.Row)
counted = rngused.Rows.Count

For i = 1 To counted
    If Left(rngused(i), 1) <> "." Then
    strDone = strDone & rngused(i)
        For j = 1 To counted
            If Left(rngused(i).Offset(j, 0), 1) = "." Then
            strDone = strDone & rngused(i).Offset(j, 0)
            ElseIf Left(rngused(i).Offset(j, 0), 1) <> "." Then
            Range("B" & i).Value = strDone
            strDone = ""
            Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next

Set rngg = Nothing
Set lastcolA = Nothing
Set rngused = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect! Zat this is amazing! Thank you, I am pretty good at the formula side of Excel but I have no idea how to do VBA, but this is just awesome! thank you!

Comment: Glad to help. BTW, before asking in SO, users are supposed to try first, when failed, post and after that someone tries to help. So, you initially got repulsive reactions. Your question was clear enough to attract answers though.